# office 2013 created excel file lost column data when opening in office 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365

I Am trying to open excel file which is created in office version 2013, And my office version is office 2016 whenever i open these file i lost all data of a column please help.]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Pzv8.png [Original Excel]
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARAiO.png [After opening]

Comment: Maybe the data was lost when you embedded the file into Word, so no way to restore it. Have you tried removing the file and embedding again?

Comment: Your Screen Shots are unable to illustrate the real situation better share file on Cloud or Drop Box!!

Comment: Rajesh- Scenario is that one of our clients is who send an excel file through email, and whenever I try to open it, I lost all data of the column, And when I open the same file in office version 2013 then its working fine.

My Office version 2016.

Comment: Is there a formula in the column in question?

Comment: No  there is no formula in the column

Comment: How did you open the file? Directly from Outlook or you have downloaded the attachment to your local computer before opening?

Answer (score 0):

A few things I found you can try:

1. Check the cell formatting. ***[Edit]***
2. Hide, unhide the column.
3. Select the column and toggle the text color to white, then back to automatic.
4. Copy the sheet to a new workbook:

   - Right-Click the sheet tab with the missing column
   - Select `Move or Copy...` to open the `Move or Copy` dialogue
   - Use the `To book:` pick list to select `(new book)`
   - Check the `Create a copy` selection box.
   - Click `OK`
   - Save the new workbook that opens.